# Unexpected result while running a unit test for the function containing setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

The following code works as expected when testing it manually in the browser's console. I receive the correct number of points with the delay of one second in the console.

```
const defer = (func, ms) => {
  return function() {
    setTimeout(() => func.call(this, ...arguments), ms);
  };
};

const playerPerformance = {
  goals: 33,
  assists: 21,
  points(penaltiesEarned) {
    console.log((this.goals * 2) + (this.assists * 1.5) + (penaltiesEarned * 1.5));
  },
};

const deferredPointsDisplay = defer(playerPerformance.points, 1000);

deferredPointsDisplay.call( { goals: 18, assists: 19 }, 7 ); // in 1 sec: 75
```

However, I struggle to write an effective unit test in index.test.js (other tests are run perfectly, so the babel and jest configurations are fine). I googled the idea of async and await, however, the examples I found on the web did not help me understand how to apply this correctly to my code. The following test fails:

```
    it('should return 75', () => {

  const playerPerformance = {
    goals: 33,
    assists: 21,
    points(penaltiesEarned) {
      console.log((this.goals * 2) + (this.assists * 1.5) + (penaltiesEarned * 1.5));
    },
  };
  
    const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

    const deferredPointsDisplay = defer2(playerPerformance.points, 1000);

    deferredPointsDisplay.call( { goals: 18, assists: 19 }, 7);
  
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(75);
});
```

I would appreciate if you help me understand how I can prevent setTimeout() from failing my unit test.

Comment: What's the goal here? Your `defer` wrapper will not return whatever `func` returns. The result of `deferredPointsDisplay` will always be `undefined`. With either of the two implementations you've shown. Do you want to make sure the function is *called*? Do you want to make sure it *logs something*? You'd need to change your test for that. If you want to have `defer` actually produce a result, it would likely need to produce a promise, which means changes to the implementation code as well.

Comment: I want to check the message logged in the console. Could you please help with how can I prevent setTimeout() from failing my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [mock `setTimeout`](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) and you can [spy on `console.log`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname). You don't need to use `async`/`await` here, your `defer()` function doesn't use promises.

Comment: I have achieved checking the result by changing what the function does (logging instead of returning) and by using spy on console.log. However, I still experience difficulty with mocking out setTimeout. What can you suggest?